# js - set element color on click issue

Tags: javascript

I tried to set color of element. but not succeed yet. Here i want to run 2 functions on click (addXXX,setcolor) too.

```
<div id="tweet">'.$tweet['text'].'</div>        
<input type="radio" name="pos" value="POS" 
       onclick="addPOS(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+\' \');
       $(#tweet).css(\'background-color\', \'red\');">
  <span class="label label-success">Pos</span>
</input>
<input type="radio" name="pos" value="NON" 
       onclick="addNON(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+\' \');
       $(#tweet).css(\'background-color\', \'blue\');">
  <span class="label label-warning">Non</span></input>
<input type="radio" name="pos" value="NEG" 
         onclick="addNEG(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+\' \');
         $(#tweet).css(\'background-color\', \'yellow\');">
  <span class="label label-important">Neg</span>
</input>';
```

Comment: Hey please indent your code men.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <div id="tweet">test</div>
 <input type="radio" name="pos" value="POS" onclick="$('#tweet').css('background-color', 'yellow');">
```

If using normal javascript,

```
<div id="tweet">test</div>
<input type="radio" name="pos" value="POS" onclick="document.getElementById('tweet').style.background = 'yellow'">
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but my color div not changed. this is why?

Comment: i think the problem comes from background-color, i use color everything gonna success.

Comment: i need to set backgroun-color property. how property should i choose?

Comment: You have to use $("#tweet").css('background-color', 'yellow'). If this doesnt works, Please share the code in which color property works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two functions into a separate function and call that method instead of running two method calls in the "onclick" property

```
<script>
function changeColor(param)
{
    addPOS(param.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+\' \');
    $(#tweet).css(\'background-color\', \'red\');
}
</script>
<input type="radio" name="pos" value="POS" onclick="changeColor(this)">
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color on the div onclick.
try this.

```
<div id="tweet"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor='red'"/>
```